# In xlsx i wanted to split the single column in to multiple using delimiter ',' using python

Tags: python, excel

The Picture below shows an excel sheet  which is taken as input(in which all the strings are separated by "," and are in the first column)

[image: Excel sheet]

Output: An excel sheet in which all the strings are split by the comma as delimiter and should be seen in successive columns

Please help me out!!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could open the file in a text editor, find/replace each comma with a tab, and then paste the tab-delimited result into a fresh Excel file.  Otherwise, consider writing a custom function that utilizes the VBA `Split()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try :

```
wb = Workbook(your_filename)
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
openfile = open(yourfile, 'rt')
filereader = csv.reader(openfile)
for posr, rows in enumerate(filereader):
    for posc, col_info in enumerate(rows):
        ws.write(posr, posc, col_info)
wb.close()
```

You might need to import the following libs:

```
import os
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import csv
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!It worked :D